# how to call a variable defined below it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following code and i'm trying to console log a variable called trt i created below it: how can i get trt in console log??
thanks

```
          this.rows = this.dataService.SetItem('added-items',());{
      console.log(trt);
      this.dataService.GetJson().subscribe((result)=>
      {
        this.rows=(JSON.parse(result['_body'])); 
        var trt=(result['_body']); 
          //this.rows = this.dataService.SetItem("data",this.rows);

  })
```

thanks!!

Comment: Put the `console.log()` call in the callback to the `.subscribe()` call.

Comment: i need to use the variable trt here: ('added-items',(trt));

Answer (score 0):

You need to log it to the console after you define it.

```
this.rows = this.dataService.SetItem('added-items',());{
  //console.log(trt);
  this.dataService.GetJson().subscribe((result)=>
  {
    this.rows=(JSON.parse(result['_body'])); 
    var trt=(result['_body']); 
     console.log(trt);
      //this.rows = this.dataService.SetItem("data",this.rows);
```

})

Edit: you cannot call a variable that has not been defined yet and expect it to not be undefined.

Comment: i need its value at the above row in order to use it here ('added-items',(trt));

Comment: @EladNachum you could get 'trt' and setup a recursive function to loop back when it's gotten that data.

Comment: how do i do that?? i need the var trt to get a value and than return to ('added-items',(trt)); so i can put it in localstorage

Comment: @EladNachum you run the callback inside that function with an if statement to check if you've gotten it. If you have stop execution of that function.

Comment: @EladNachum what you're describing is an impossible thing. You're saying I don't want an apple from the tree but I want am apple before I plant the tree.